# jquery for redirecting to another controller mvc

Tags: jquery

so i want to redirecting to another controller with jquery after the log in proccess succeded.
but instead the page only redirecting to itself.
ive tried all 3 possibilities of the jquery its only couldnt redirect to another controller.

the proccess likely: form[post] ->controller->back to jquery->redirect to dashboard page

https://file.town/download/e2dhyf2yyabpn6kuh79q3dylo here is the source code if u want to try it.

here is the view.php

```
<?php include('Header.php'); ?>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    ..........
        <?php echo form_open('Login/check_login')?>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s6 m12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                        <input id="nim" type="text" class="validate" name="nim">
                        <label for="nim">NIM</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s6 m12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">visibility_off</i>
                        <input id="password" type="password" class="validate" name="password">
                        <label for="password">Password</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col s6 m12">
                        <button type="submit" value="login" class="waves-effect waves-light btn #1976d2 blue darken-2 submit1">LOGIN</button>
                        <button type="reset" value="cancel" class="waves-effect waves-light btn #1976d2 blue darken-2">CANCEL</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php echo form_close()?>
   .......
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".submit1").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var nim     = $("#nim").val();
            var password    = $("#password").val();     
            jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"Login/check_login",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {nim:nim, password:password},
            success: function(res) {
                if(res.hasil == 'a'){
                    swal({
                        title: "Login sukses",
                        text: "Horeee",
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#0760ef',
                        type:"success"});
                    window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('User');?>";
                }else if(res.hasil == 'u'){
                    swal({
                        title: "Login sukses",
                        text: "Horeee",
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#0760ef',
                        type:"success"});
                    window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('User');?>";
                }else{
                    swal({
                        title: "Login Gagal",
                        text: "Pastikan NIM dan Password Benar",
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#0760ef',
                        type:"error"});
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

here is the controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class login extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    // Load form helper library
    $this->load->helper('form');

    // Load form validation library
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    // Load session library
    $this->load->library('session');

    // Load database model
    $this->load->model('Mlogin');
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('login/Vlogin');
}
public function check_login()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('nim', 'NIM', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE ){
        $this->load->view('login/Vlogin');
    }
    else{
        $akun = array(
        'nim'       => $this->input->post('nim'),
        'password'  => md5($this->input->post('password'))
        );

        $result = $this->Mlogin->check_akun($akun);
        if($result != false){
            $result = $this->Mlogin->get_information($akun);
                $session_data = array(
                    'nim'   => $akun['nim'],
                    'nama'  => $result[0]->nama,
                    'gambar'=> $result[0]->name,
                    'akses' => $result[0]->akses,
                    'status' => $result[0]->status,
                    'loggedin' => true,
                    );
                $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $session_data);
            if ($result[0]->akses=='a') {
                $hasil['hasil'] = 'a';
                echo json_encode($hasil);
            }
            else{
                $hasil['hasil'] = 'u';
                echo json_encode($hasil);
            }
        }
        else
        {   
            $hasil['hasil'] = 'false';
            echo json_encode($hasil);
        }
    }
}
```

or maybe there is any alternative ??

Comment: is your button actually a submit button, or a standard button?  I would think that your form is still being submitted.  It's a little hard to say, as you have not included your rendered form html.  maybe try and handle `$("form").submit()` instead

Comment: ive add the form code in the view, im not sure which type of button im using

Comment: Try using submit event on the form instead of click on button

Answer (score 1):

Your `form` is submitting before your ajax completes.

I would suggest you handle the `form submit` event instead; for debugging purposes I have replaced your redirects with alerts instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var nim     = $("#nim").val();
        var password    = $("#password").val();     
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"+"Login/check_login",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {nim:nim, password:password},
            success: function(res) {
                if(res.hasil == 'a'){
                    swal({
                        title: "Login sukses",
                        text: "Horeee",
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#0760ef',
                        type:"success"});
                    //window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('User');?>";
                    alert(res.hasil);
                }else if(res.hasil == 'u'){
                    swal({
                        title: "Login sukses",
                        text: "Horeee",
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#0760ef',
                        type:"success"});
                    //window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('User');?>";
                    alert(res.hasil);
                }else{
                    swal({
                        title: "Login Gagal",
                        text: "Pastikan NIM dan Password Benar",
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#0760ef',
                        type:"error"});
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```